# How to print specific value from specific key from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I wrote 2 functions so I can get champion ID knowing champion Name but then I wanted to get champion Name knowing champion ID but I cannot figure it out how to extract the name because of how the data structured.

```
"data":{"Aatrox":{"version":"8.23.1","id":"Aatrox","key":"266","name":"Aatrox"
```

so in my code I wrote `['data']['championName'(in this case Aatrox)]['key']` to get the champion ID/key. But how can I reverse it if for example I don't know the champion Name but champions ID. How can I get the champion Name if after writing ['data'] I need to write champion Name so I can go deeper and get all the champions info like ID, title etc..

link: http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.23.1/data/en_US/champion.json

Code:

```
def requestChampionData(championName):
    name = championName.lower()
    name = name.title()
    URL = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.23.1/data/en_US/champion/" + name + ".json"
    response = requests.get(URL)
    return response.json()

def championID(championName):
    championData = requestChampionData(championName)
    championID = str(championData['data'][championName]['key'])
    return championID
```

Comment: It's rarely (like, never) a good idea to duplicate data in a database, JSON included. I suggest restructuring your JSON so that the champion name is in the innermost block with the rest of the data. That will meet both (and other) methods of accessing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code:

```
def championNameByID(id):
    championData = requestChampionData()
    allChampions = championData['data']
    for champion in allChampions:
        if id == allChampions[champion]['key']:
            championName = allChampions[champion]['name']
            return championName
```

Answer (score 0):

since python values are passed by reference you can make a new dict with keys as the champion id pointing to the values of the previous dict, that way you dont duplicate too much data. but be carefull if you change data in one dict the data will be changed in the other one too

```
def new_dict(d):
  return { val["id"]:val for val in d.values() }
```